# PyScripter Import ARGV

Tags: python, argv

Not too sure how to get the following code to work properly in PyScripter.

```
from sys import argv

script, user_name = argv
prompt = '> '

print "Hi %s, I'm the %s script." % (user_name, script)
print "I'd like to ask you a few question."
print "Do you like me %s?" % user_name
likes = raw_input(prompt)

print "Where do you live %s?" %user_name
lives = raw_input(prompt)

print "What kind of computer do you have?"
computer = raw_input(prompt)

print """
Alright, so you said %r about liking me.
You live in %r. Not sure where the fuck that is!
And you have a %r computer. It's obviously a piece of shit!
""" % (likes, lives, computer)
```

Thanks.

Comment: so whats the problem exactly ?

Comment: ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack and highlights the script, user_name = argv

Answer (score 0):

As you unpack the `argv` to 2 variable you need to pass `user_name` in terminal.

```
from sys import argv
script, user_name = argv

print user_name
```

Demo:

```
/Desktop$ python p.py userrrr
userrrr
```

but if you dont pass the username at runtime you will get that error :

```
~/Desktop$ python p.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "p.py", line 51, in <module>
    script, user_name = argv
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack
```

Comment: i guess i should have added that i am new, and a brief explanation would be great!

Comment: @JustinKowalsky yes you need to add it in run time !